# Asp.Net Core - Using responseCache with ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

here's my ViewComponent:

```
public class Categories: ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categories;

    public Categories(ICategoryService categories)
    {
        _categories = categories;
    }      


    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var cat = _categories.GetCategories();
        return View(viewName: "Default", model: cat);
    }        
}
```

and here's how I use it in my view:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Categories")
```

I tried use caching by putting:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 99999999)]
```

above invoke method but didn't work.

Is it possible to use caching with view components? and how?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can cache View Components by wrapping them in a cache tag helper, like this:

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Categories")
</cache>
```

Comment: See [Cache Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=email) for documentation of the various arguments.